# vim replace all lines after a given line

Tags: vim

I want to replace using vim command, right now I'm doing

`:num1, num2 s /word/newWord/g`

However, how can I do something like all lines after a number

something like

`:num1, infinity s /word/newWord/g`

`:num1,  s /word/newWord/g`
This recognize only the num1 line.

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#[range]

Comment: @melpomene thanks. I was searching "line range" in the documentation and couldn't find it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$` is used to mark the last line of file so you can do this with this command:

```
:num1,$ s/word/newWord/g
```